# Why is add-in toolbar greyed out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in

I installed an addIn toolbar for the [U.S. Geological Survey's National Cooperative Geologic Mapping Program](http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/Info/standards/NCGMP09/) and I can see it, but all the tools are greyed out.

Any idea why I can't see it? I am inserting a jpg of what I see.

[image: greyedouttoolbar]

Comment: Just curious (I don't know anything about this add-in), are you able to access the "NCGMP Menu"? Could you screenshot that as well?

Comment: 2 different answers below suggested you try to start an edit session to see whether the event will enable the toolbar buttons.  Have you had a chance to try this?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the **[current source code](https://github.com/ncgmp09/azgs-toolbar/blob/master/btnDatabaseMaintenance.cs)**, but it does look like a lot of buttons are tied to an edit session and if the extension enabled.

Also go to Menu Customization-->Extensions and see if there is an entry for your extension that is unchecked.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possiblities. One would be the addin was not installed correctly. Mostly likely the issue is that some tools are only available in certain situations. For example, you must be in an edit session, must have a certain type of data loaded, or must have a feature selected.

Based on the menu name in the image you posted, it looks like in your case you need to start an edit session to enable the tools.  Take a look at [this pdf](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/mining13/papers/2013.07.05-ncgmp.ags-day.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (not guaranteed) might be to open the installation file. I once reopened an installation file in order to identify the exact file the toolbar was stored in (to remove it with the Add-in manager). The developers had placed the tool removal option in the the installation package.